# Usage of SASS value variables: best practics

Tags: css, sass, node-sass, css-variables

Does it make sense to use sass variables when repeating values?
For example:

```
$common-px-value: 20px
$max-value: 100px
$min-value: 200px
.someClass, someAnotherClass
  some styles...
  img
    object-fit: cover
    min-width: $min-value
    max-width: $max-value
    min-height: $min-value
    max-height: $max-value
```

***What the best practics with SASS value variables?***
Maybe add it to separate folder for separation of logic? And something else:)

**Does it use only for readability of code?** 
What a good practices at real projects?
After all, values can be repeated throughout the all application, but it's hard to find out all values beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mixin for this, which would make your code more dry and easy to use. So you could do something like

```
@mixin myValues(
$minw: null,
$maxw: null
) {
min-width: $minw;
max-width: $maxw;
}
```

and then you can use that mixin in the styles for .someClass like so:

```
.someClass {
 @include myValues($minw: 200px, $maxw: 200px);
}
```

You can change the values of the arguments you pass to that mixin each time you need to, instead of repeating the same chunk of code each time. Hope that helps.

Edit: The sass syntax might be a bit different than scss (which I used in this example)